# Automapper with complex configuration

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a `json` object

```
{
  "userId": 12,
  "email": "demo@example.com",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "customerName": "Microsoft"
  "contents": [
    {
      "productId": 34,
      "productName": "Product 1",
      "productCost": "35.50",
      "quantity": 3
    },
    {
      "productId": 35,
      "productName": "Product 2",
      "productCost": "40.99",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

that I post to my `WebApi`

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(ShoppingCartDto shoppingCart)
        {    
            var result = _service.AddToCart(shoppingCart);
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

then I use `automapper` to map the `ShoppingCartDto` to all correct domain classes.

So here is the problem, how can use `automapper` to first to go and lookup an `customerId` before i actually to the mapping.
[image]

I have to lookup the `customerId` from the `Customer table` so that when i map to the Tokens table i have the `customerId`

The mapping i have so far

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ShoppingCartDto, User>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserId))
    .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
    {
        var token = (Mapper.Map<Token>(dest));

        token.CustomerId = "Can I do database lookup here" 

        dest.Tokens.Add(token);

        foreach (var content in Mapper.Map<Cart[]>(src.Contents))
        {
            token.Contents.Add(content);
        }
    });
```

Or should I use some sort of Custom Resolver.

My mappings are sitting in an `AutoMapperConfig` file inside the `App_Start` folder. So I am not a 100% sure how to go about it. I know I can do the mapping manually but i want to keep all the mappings for `Automapper`

Comment: Why do you prefer to do this with AutoMapper?

Comment: Honestly, it is just to keep my code clean. I am just trying to keep my services and controllers small.

Answer (score 2):

Since your mapping process requires access to some service (data access in your case), it is better to encapsulate the mapping process in some service like this:

```
public interface IMapper<TSource, TDestination>
{
    TDestination Map(TSource source);
}

public class ShoppingCartDtoToUserMapper : IMapper<ShoppingCartDto, User>
{
    private IDataAccessor m_DataAccessor; //This can be a repository for example, I am just using IDataAccessor as an example

    public ShoppingCartDtoToUserMapper(IDataAccessor data_accessor)
    {
        m_DataAccessor = data_accessor;
    }

    public User Map(ShoppingCartDto source)
    {
        //Use AutoMapper here as you did and also use m_DataAccessor for any data access operations
    }
}
```

You should use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to properly construct the `ShoppingCartDtoToUserMapper` dependency and inject it (as `IMapper<ShoppingCartDto, User>`) into the class the requires mapping functionality from `ShoppingCartDto` to `User`.

Comment: So, you got me thinking... if i really need to do it in Automapper, i don't think the juice is worth the squeeze. In the end of the day i don't think business logic should live inside the automapper setups. + 1 because i really like your answer